# Need to proper way to run just single script and re-create docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

I had created one `dockerimage` whose size is more than `2GB` Now I want to reduce the size of the file to remove some lines and rebuild this file. I don't have `dockerfile` for the same.

```
docker history --no-trunc
```

I know the above command, but I want `dockerfile` except copy and paste into `dockerfile`.

I want script to just run it and return the whole `Dockerfile`.

Recently, i had created `python` script to fetch docker history but it was give me data like this format.

```
[
  {
    'Comment': 'buildkit.dockerfile.v0',
    'Created': 1659415912,
    'CreatedBy': 'CMD ["hadoop" "namenode" "-format"]',
    'Id': '*',
    'Size': 0,
    'Tags': None
  },
  {
    'Comment': 'buildkit.dockerfile.v0',
    'Created': 1659415912,
    'CreatedBy': 'EXPOSE map[10020/tcp:{} 19888/tcp:{} 19890/tcp:{} 50010/tcp:{} 50020/tcp:{} 50070/tcp:{} 50075/tcp:{} 50090/tcp:{} 8020/tcp:{} 8030/tcp:{} 8031/tcp:{} 8032/tcp:{} 8033/tcp:{} 8040/tcp:{} 8042/tcp:{} 8088/tcp:{} 9000/tcp:{} 9864/tcp:{} 9870/tcp:{}]',
    'Id': '*',
    'Size': 0,
    'Tags': None
  },
]
```